# How to persist Nginx Ingress Controller Session affinity even after a re-deployment/node-restart

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

This might sound like bit impractical and at the same time I want to evaluate the possibilities where I can setup session affinity in the `nginx` in my Kubernetes cluster, and still persist the cookies even after the following scenarios

- Node currently hosting the application gets restarted
- Kubernetes cluster gets updated

The default `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"` is not working after testing the above scenarios.

Could someone please give me some insights on this?

Comment: The session affinity depends upon caching, however in kubernetes this caching will get affected when the node restarts or the deployment restarts, in order to maintain persistent caching you might need to use some external tools like CDN, Nginx enterprise etc.. as mentioned in this [blog](https://medium.com/@vdboor/using-nginx-ingress-as-a-static-cache-91bc27be04a1)